# Find data location based on Primarykey ID

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am very new to access and vba so apologies in advance for glaring conceptual gaps.

Basically I have a button that, when clicked, prompts a user to enter an ID number. The ID entered will correspond to one of my primary keys in a specific table (I have some checks in place to make sure the entered ID is valid).

**I need my code to identify the row number of the ID entered and be able to populate a specific column in that row.** I know Access does not refer to data locations using rows/cols but that is the best way I thought to describe it.

I am using Index/Seek/NoMatch to make sure the entered ID number is valid and I have been trying to find a way to also use those functions to generate the data location but have not had any luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `update myTableName t set t.MyColumnName = 'Yes' where t.id = [your id here] `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `DLookup()` function will work for your case. Suppose you have following dataset in table `tblEmpInfo` where `EmpID` is primary key field.

[image]

If you want to return employee name by entering employee id in a inputbox then use `DLookup()` like below-

```
Private Sub cmdDataLookup_Click()
Dim strEmpName As String, InputID As String

    InputID = InputBox("Enter employee ID:", "Input ID")

    strEmpName = DLookup("EmpName", "tblEmpInfo", "EmpID= '" & InputID & "'")
    MsgBox strEmpName

End Sub
```

If you want to update any name by entering EmpID then use UPDATE SQL statement. Try below.

```
Private Sub cmdUpdateInfo_Click()
Dim strSQL As String, InputID As String
    
    InputID = InputBox("Enter employee ID:", "Input ID")
    strSQL = "UPDATE tblEmpInfo Set EmpName= 'Updated Value' WHERE EmpID= '" & InputID & "'"
    
    CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
        
End Sub
```

***Note:*** There is no direct way to get row number and column number of a `Field` in access but you can apply some trick by `VBA` to get row and column number of a `Field`. I will suggest to ask a separate question to get that.

Comment: Thank you! That is very helpful! Unfortunately when I try to run the cmdUpdateInfo_Click() code you provided above, it returns with a Data Mismatch Type error. I have tried changing the data type in the table but it seems that was not the issue. Any thoughts?

Comment: In my answer I have used all the field as Short Text. Based on data type codes may need to change. Can you show us your table structure and few smple data and how you used the codes to your database.

Comment: I actually got it to run using this variation: DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE TableName SET FieldName='" & Update & "' WHERE IDNumber=" & ID & ""     I think my issue was that one of my table fields is a long number. Thank you for all your help!!!

Comment: If the answer helps then consider accepting it. Tick mark the answer as green so that other visitor can know this answer solved your issue.